# How to import extremely long JavaScript const into an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript const that is a couple thousand lines long. When I include this constant, which is an array of objects, directly inside the  tags in my index.html file, the constant is available for use in the chart library I'm using. However, if I try to import that const into the script tags of the chart library, it's not available.

How can I successfully import a JS const into an html file so it can be used within the script tags.

The script tags in the html file I have are set up as:

```
<script>
    import { extremelyLongJSConst } from "./example.js";
other js content
</script>
```

And the example.js JS file exports the const using:

```
export const extremelyLongJSConst = {
lots of info
}
```

I've tried defining the script tags as type="module", but have had no success and am not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible in this context.

Comment: us the alias `import { extremelyLongJSConst as smallText } from "./example.js";`

Comment: that doesn't work either. i would have thought aliasing would be the same.

Comment: it's an array of objects that have strings in it

Comment: it won't work. it's not possible to import into an html file and be available. it's possibly the charting library, but i think it's the import itself.

Comment: First of all, `<script type="module">` *is* required. Then check your browser’s console for errors, e.g. about the same origin policy.

Comment: do you know how to get passed the same origin policy?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your HTML:

```
<script type="module">
    import longJSON from './longJSON.js';
    console.log(longJSON);
</script
```

The longJSON.js

```
export default {
    some: 'super fancy content'
};
```

Information about modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

with best regards

Comment: this gets blocked because of a Cors policy

Comment: Well you didnt mentioned that you are trying to request a file from another domain. To enable CORS the server you are requesting to has to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`to its header

Comment: this occurs just importing the js file into an html file. multiple domains aren't involved nor are servers.

Comment: I uploaded a test on my domain: https://samuelweber.at/test.html - output can be found in the console

Comment: weird. i'm still seeing: Access to script...from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: If you are using the same [SCHEME]://[HOST]:[PORT] it should be fine. You're sure you are not requesting a static asset from a server running on another port?

Comment: i'm not running a server. i'm just trying this in Vs Code. with an html and js file, and an array of objects.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas :(