# How can I import a json file in a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have two files `data.json` and `index.js`.

`data.json` looks like this:

```
{
      "stacy": {
           "age": 24,
           "name": "Stacy",
           "properties": [ "crazy", "funny", "straight" ]
      },
      "john": {
           "age": 41,
           "name": "John",
           "properties": [ "experienced", "direct", "straight" ]
      },
}
```

How can I import `data.json` into `index.js`?

I thought about something like this: `import * as persons from data.json;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import extremely long JavaScript const into an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634946/how-to-import-extremely-long-javascript-const-into-an-html-file)

Comment: You should add whether you are using Node or the browser. In browser you need to use `fetch`, in Node you can use `require`.

Comment: In the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find all of your JSON data in the `data` variable.

By using fetch API you can load JSON data. Code below:

```
fetch('data.json')
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console(err));
```

try to write the exact file location.